# i want to create salt and pepper noise function (PIL and Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to create salt and pepper noise function.
The input is noise_density, i.e. the amount of pixels as noise in the output image and it should return value is the noisy image data source

```
def salt_pepper(noise_density):



noisesource = ColumnDataSource(data={'image': [noiseImage]})
return noisesource
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns an image that is [density]x[density] pixels, using numpy to generate a random array and using PIL to generate the image itself from the array.

```
def salt_pepper(density):
    imarray = numpy.random.rand(density,density,3) * 255
    return Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8')).convert('L')
```

Now, for example, you could run

```
salt_pepper(500)
```

To generate an image file that is 500x500px.

Of course, make sure to

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Consider adding at least some comments - an explanation, what a code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a vectorized solution which I'm sure can be improved/simplified. Although the interface is not exactly as the requested one, the code is pretty straightforward (and fast ) and I'm sure it can be easily adapted.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def salt_and_pepper(image, prob=0.05):
    # If the specified `prob` is negative or zero, we don't need to do anything.
    if prob <= 0:
        return image

    arr = np.asarray(image)
    original_dtype = arr.dtype

    # Derive the number of intensity levels from the array datatype.
    intensity_levels = 2 ** (arr[0, 0].nbytes * 8)

    min_intensity = 0
    max_intensity = intensity_levels - 1

    # Generate an array with the same shape as the image's:
    # Each entry will have:
    # 1 with probability: 1 - prob
    # 0 or np.nan (50% each) with probability: prob
    random_image_arr = np.random.choice(
        [min_intensity, 1, np.nan], p=[prob / 2, 1 - prob, prob / 2], size=arr.shape
    )

    # This results in an image array with the following properties:
    # - With probability 1 - prob: the pixel KEEPS ITS VALUE (it was multiplied by 1)
    # - With probability prob/2: the pixel has value zero (it was multiplied by 0)
    # - With probability prob/2: the pixel has value np.nan (it was multiplied by np.nan)
    # We need to to `arr.astype(np.float)` to make sure np.nan is a valid value.
    salt_and_peppered_arr = arr.astype(np.float) * random_image_arr

    # Since we want SALT instead of NaN, we replace it.
    # We cast the array back to its original dtype so we can pass it to PIL.
    salt_and_peppered_arr = np.nan_to_num(
        salt_and_peppered_arr, nan=max_intensity
    ).astype(original_dtype)

    return Image.fromarray(salt_and_peppered_arr)
```

You can load a black and white version of [Lena](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/lena.ppm) like so:

```
lena = Image.open("lena.ppm")
bwlena = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(lena).mean(axis=2).astype(np.uint8))
```

Finally, you can save a couple of examples:

```
salt_and_pepper(bwlena, prob=0.1).save("sp01lena.png", "PNG")
salt_and_pepper(bwlena, prob=0.3).save("sp03lena.png", "PNG")
```

Results:

https://i.ibb.co/J2y9HXS/sp01lena.png

https://i.ibb.co/VTm5Vy2/sp03lena.png